# Lighting in computer vision systems

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I don't know if the question is well suited for stackoverflow but also it's hard to fit it to image processing.

Question is about lighting setups in computer vision systems.

Can someone provide reference to materials about lighting setups. When to use backlight, darkfield etc. How to improve features detection by lighting tricks.

I know that good lighting makes image-processing easier and want to get familiar with theory about it.

Answer (score 1):

Transform your image into the Lab color space. The l channel represents the lighting.

Comment: Thanks for new thing. It acctually does not answer my question but helps a lot in visualizing illumination of element.